# How to send multiple parameters using Axios and access them using Java Spring Boot service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vue.js, axios

I am developing an application using `Nuxtjs/Vuejs`. Within that, I am using `Axios` to send some data to my `Java Spring-boot service`.

I would like to send multiple parameters within my `Axios Post` request and access them using the `Java Spring-boot`. I am able to make it work for a single parameter but when I pass multiple parameters then I get the error `Required request body is missing` within the `Java service`.

My `Axios Post` request:

```
export const actions = {
    testdataGenerator ({ commit, state, dispatch }) {  
        const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

        this.$axios.post('/generateTestData', { params: { inputTemplate: state.testDataInput, identifiersTemplate: state.identifiersData } }, { headers })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })
    }
}
```

`Java Spring Boot service`:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestDataGeneratorController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/generateTestData", consumes = "application/json   ", produces = "text/plain")
    public String generateTestData(@RequestBody String inputTemplate, @RequestBody String identifiersTemplate) throws TestDataGeneratorException {
        try {
            System.out.println(inputTemplate);
            System.out.println(identifiersTemplate);
            return null;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new TestDataGeneratorException(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I need to change within my `Axios/Java service` to make the `POST request` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are sending data with axios to the spring boot controller in the correct way, the problem stands in the multiple [`RequestBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) annotations in your method :

```
public String generateTestData(@RequestBody String inputTemplate,
 @RequestBody String identifiersTemplate) throws TestDataGeneratorException
```

In case of multiple params contained in the body of the request one of the ways to solve is the conversion to a `Map<String, Object>` and then inside the body extract the parameters :

```
public String generateTestData(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> map) 
throws TestDataGeneratorException {
//your map will be {params={inputTemplate=..., identifiersTemplate=...}}
}
```

The message *Required request body is missing* is probably due to the multiple `RequestBody` annotations and related to the presence of the second annotation that according to the message receives an empty body, but I am not sure about it.